# Updated WordPress and now image crop, thumbnail setting and thumbnails are gone

Tags: php, image, wordpress, thumbnails

I've updated to WordPress 3.7.1 and when I upload images to my site, it's not generating thumbnails. It's also missing the image crop and thumbnail setting sidebar.

I created a simple theme but didn't make any kind of changes. Everything was working just fine up until the update.

I'm also using the default WordPress Gallery.

I've been searching but can't find anything on this.

Please help, thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for our sister site [wordpress.se]?

Comment: Try do a clean install of WP 3.7.1 and see if the functions are still there.

Comment: Thanks Michael Hampton, posted there as well. Steven I tried reinstalling but I'm running into the same issue. Even when switching to one of the default themes, the same thing is happening.